# Redirecionamento de páginas com .htaccess php

Tags: php, htaccess

Gostaria de saber se tem como com .htaccess, fazer o seguinte redirecionamento:

Url: https://exemplo.com/vendas e https://exemplo.com/admin

Quando o usuario digitar ou vendas ou admin ele redirecionar para a página:

https://exemplo.com/acesso/index

Comment: Tem sim. Existe a diretiva `Redirect` para isso.

Answer (score 0):

Existem várias formas de redirecionar os acessos do seu site.

Conheça alguns deles:

Redirecionando o domínio principal da conta: RedirectMatch ^/$ http://dominio.com.br/diretorio
Redireciona “www.dominio.com.br” para “www.dominio.com.br/loja”
Redirect 301 /pagina.html http://www.seudominio.com.br/novapagina.html
Redireciona o acesso ao arquivo “pagina.html” para “http://www.seudominio.com.br/novapagina.html”

Redirect 301 / http://www.dominio.com.br/
Redireciona o acesso de sua conta para o endereço “http://www.dominio.com.br/”

RedirectMatch 301 (.*).html$ http://www.seudominio.com.br$1.php
Caso você tenha mudado todos os seus arquivos de extensão “.html” para “.php” e tenha links antigos com referências para os “.html”, você pode evitar que o usuário acesse uma página que não existe mais com essa linha; Ela redireciona qualquer acesso a um “.html” substituindo “.html” para “.php”.

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^site.com.br
RewriteRule (.*) http://site.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]